# How is modifier key remapping implemented on Touchbar Macbooks?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, touch-bar, nvram

How is modifier key remapping implemented on Touchbar Macbooks?  Is it done by the main OS, or is it delegated to a controller associated with the keyboard itself?

I understand that the Touch Bar and Facetime Camera are [run by embedded microprocessors running "Bridge OS"](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IBridge) (see also the article linked in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/261981/9842)).  Is that processor is also responsible for running the keyboard?  Does it have its own configuration memory that may be used to store modifier key remapping settings?

I am having a difficult to reproduce [freeze-on-wake issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348876/whats-causing-my-macbook-to-freeze-and-reset-keyboard-settings-when-i-bring-it) with my 2018 Touchbar MacBook Pro that sometimes resets the modifier key remapping that I configured back to the default mapping.  My machine recently crashed during one of these freezes, and the crash report mentioned the OS version was `Bridge OS 3.3 (16P3133)` and the panic message was `userspace panic: remoted connection watchdog expired, no updates from  remoted monitoring thread in 75 seconds`.

I'm wondering if the Bridge OS processor is defective on my machine, and the freezes during wake, the keyboard configuration resets, and the recent crash during wake could all be symptoms of its dysfunction.

---

**OS**: Mojave 10.14.3 (18D109)

**Hardware**: MacBookPro15,1

---

Here's the modifier key remapping configuration I'm talking about:

[image: modifier key remapping configuration dialog box]

---

System Information reports that my keyboard is attached to the "iBridge Bus":

```
iBridge Bus:

  Host Controller Driver:   AppleUSBVHCIBCE

iBridge DFR brightness:

  Product ID:   0x8102
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  2.01
  Serial Number:    000000000000
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID:  0x80700000

iBridge Display:

  Product ID:   0x8302
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  2.01
  Serial Number:    0000000000000000
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID:  0x80600000

Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad:

  Product ID:   0x027c
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  9.27
  Serial Number:    [redacted]
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID:  0x80500000 / 8
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    500
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
  Built-In: Yes

Headset:

  Product ID:   0x5043
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  0.01
  Serial Number:    000000000000
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Apple
  Location ID:  0x80400000 / 3
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    500
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
  Built-In: Yes

iBridge ALS:

  Product ID:   0x8262
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  2.01
  Serial Number:    000000000000
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID:  0x80300000

iBridge FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in):

  Product ID:   0x8514
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  2.01
  Serial Number:    [redacted]
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID:  0x80200000

iBridge:

  Product ID:   0x8233
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  2.01
  Serial Number:    0000000000000000
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID:  0x80100000
```